# Tensorflow 1.3 opencl support

Tags: tensorflow

I browsed the Tensorflow code and stumbled upon OpenCL keywords several times. 
Can TensorFlow 1.3 now be used with a non Nvidia GPU?
Has anybody tried that? There is no mentioning in the documentation yet on this topic.
QUESTION: if this is possible, how? Can you guide me to steps necessary?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belong to their github page.

Comment: The github page says to use this forum in the first place :D

Comment: this you are not asking a question how to do something. You ask whether something is supported because the documentation is confusing. People who created TF know for sure whether it is supported or not

Comment: I did reedit to point to a quesiton.

Comment: I think you can't understand the point. I was not telling "please add irrelevant question in the end of your question just for the sake of having a questionmark at the end". I told that based on my experience the question is a bad fit here and should be closed and downvoted. The question is a good fit for the github page of this library. Will ask one more time **have you tried to ask a question there?**

Answer (score 0):

There is an ongoing implementation for enabling OpenCL devices with TensorFlow that uses ComputeCpp, an implementation of the open standard SYCL.

Currently the implementation supports the hardware listed [here](https://developer.codeplay.com/computecppce/latest/supported-platforms) but more hardware platforms are being added as well as optimization work to improve the performance of specific architectures.

There is an overview and getting started guide [here](https://developer.codeplay.com/computecppce/latest/tensorflow-overview)